# How do I return a string from a method in java

Tags: java

I wrote a few lines of code to find the multiples of a number in java using two classes. How do I return a string from a method.

```
class Multiples {

    String printMult(int x) {
        int i,j;

        for (i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j <= x; j++) {
               return i + "*" + j;
            }
        }
    }
}


public class Chkmult {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Multiples num = new Multiples();
        System.out.println(num.printMult(8));
    }
}
`
```

Comment: The same way you return anything from a method.  Does this code you've written fail in some specific way?  Is there an error?  An unexpected result?

Comment: First of all in SOP statement will have semicolon ;

Comment: return i + "*" + j; this line returns a string, you are already returning a string what was you are asking for?

Comment: What is the expected result you want to get?

Comment: Have you tried to compile it? Is it compiled?

Comment: you are doing it. maybe you just need an additional return statement after your for-loops, as a default.

Comment: [Check these answers first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556154/java-how-to-pass-and-return-string-method)

Comment: What you want is to create a `String` in the loop then return the `String`. What you want is concatenate a `String` (but better is to use a `StringBuilder`). I let you do some research on this "String concatenation" to see what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for `x` to be 0, and your for-loops won't iterate.
In this scenario, your `return statement` will never be reached.

In order to be compilable code, your method must have a `return statement` for each possible scenario.

Change your code to this:

```
class Multiples{
     String printMult(int x){
         int i,j;
         for(i = 0;i <= x;i++){
            for(j = 0;j <= x;j++){
               return i + "*" + j;
            }
         }
         return "no iterations occurred.";
     }
}
public class Chkmult{
   public static void main(String[] args){
        Multiples num = new Multiples();
        System.out.println(num.printMult(8))
   }
}
```

You can also remove the second return statement, and throw an Exception, but then you'll need to handle this exception in the calling method.

EDIT:
As AxelH already pointed out, what you want to do is probably not have a return statement in the for loop itself. That way, the first time you iterate there, the method will ended and only part of the information will be returned.

You could try to change that method to something like this:

```
String printMult(int x){
             int i,j;
             StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("");
             for(i = 0;i <= x;i++){
                for(j = 0;j <= x;j++){
                   buf.append(i + "*" + j + "\n");
                }
             }
             return buf.toString();
         }
```

Comment: True but I guess he mostly want to print the multiplication table from `0 * 0` to `8 * 8` or he would not needed those loops ;)

Comment: @AxelH yes, he will probably need to improve his code, no doubt that your StringBuffer/concatenation comment is valid, but his problem is his code won't compile, since he didn't provide a return statement for each possible scenario.

Comment: That's why I agreed with you on your answer. My point is just a supposition (easy but still no proof) so your answer is the only valid at this point.